# Running firefox addon fails with Syntax Error when JSON is escaped in package.json

Tags: json, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm making a firefox addon (SDK/Jetpack), and am using the Simple-Prefs module. I want to have an array in one of my preferences, so in my package.json I have written it as

```
{
  [...]
  "preferences":[
  [...]
  {
    "name":"audio-priority",
    "title":"Audio Priority",
    "type":"string",
    "value":"[\"audio-notifications\",\"audio-error\",\"audio-messages\",\"audio-youtube\",\"audio-twitch\"]",
    "hidden":true
  },
  [...]
}
```

But when I run it, it builds and the browser opens, but in the console it comes up with

```
console.error: ltt-notifier: 
  Message: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
  Stack:
    evaluate@resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///tmp/tmpn5QUOo.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-23jjnBCWPFQ3ag@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js:223
setDefaultPrefs@resource://gre/modules/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///tmp/tmpn5QUOo.mozrunner/extensions/jid1-23jjnBCWPFQ3ag@jetpack.xpi!/bootstrap.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:66
```

And a whole load more stuff afterwards (stack), and the addon is not running.
If I change the array to anything that does not have the \" (or any escaped characters - I tried using \u0022 instead) in, it works fine, which makes me think it could be a Mozilla Bug, but it is probably my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on links from https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501156 (which links to https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/json/conversations/topics/1286 ) I have figured out that the answer is that it should be

```
"[\\\"audio-notifications\\\",\\\"audio-error\\\",\\\"audio-messages\\\",\\\"audio-youtube\\\",\\\"audio-twitch\\\"]",
```

because the first time the JSON is decoded it unescapes the \" to ", but JSON requires it to still be \". By escaping the \ as well as the ", the first time it is parsed, when the entire file gets processed, it turns into

```
[\"audio-notifications\",\"audio-error\",\"audio-messages\",\"audio-youtube\",\"audio-twitch\"]
```

Which no longer closes the quotes (which I presume was an issue because the error related to an evaluate command in the native code), and means it will still be valid JSON when it comes to be decoded.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you do

`'["audio-notifications","audio-error","audio-messages","audio-youtube","audio-twitch"]'`

or

`"['audio-notifications','audio-error','audio-messages','audio-youtube','audio-twitch']"`?

If so, you should [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided#h=dupes|Add-on%20SDK|General).

Comment: The first method fails immediately as a JSON parse error (the addon does not build), and the 2nd method works, but is not ideal because I parse it as JSON later, so would have to convert it.
I'll File a bug report